# Selecting multiple names using SelectBuffer OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I'm having a rather difficult time with OpenGL's Picking mechanism using select buffers. Specifically, I want to be able to make sub-selections within a selected object. My test world has multiple objects scattered about, each which renders with four "faces", like this:

```
void drawObject(int i)
{
    renderFace0(i);
    renderFace1(i);
    renderFace2(i);
    renderFace3(i);
}
```

All is well so far. The parameter `i` just says what the index is, since my "objects" are just data stored in an array. Each object is uniquely identified based on it's index. Then I add the picking function, which updates which object is currently being pointed at (I use the center of the screen as the point which picks the objects):

```
void pickObject()
{
    unsigned int selectBuffer[200];
    int viewport[4];
    int hits;

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glSelectBuffer(200, selectBuffer);

    glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

    glInitNames();
    glPushName(0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0f, (double)width / (double)height, 0.05f, 100.0f);

    double centerX = (double)width / 2.0;
    double centerY = (double)height / 2.0;

    gluPickMatrix(centerX, centerY, 5.0f, 5.0f, viewport);
    transformWorld();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OBJECTS; i ++)
    {
        glLoadName(i + 1);
        drawObject(i);
    }

    hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
    if(hits > 0)
    {
        int znear;
        znear = selectBuffer[2];
        selected = selectBuffer[3];

        for(i = 1; i < hits; i ++)
        {
            if(selectBuffer[4 * i + 2] > znear)
            {
                znear = selectBuffer[4 * i + 2];
                selected = selectBuffer[4 * i + 3];
            }
        }

    } else selected = -1;

    glPopName();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}
```

I should note at this point that I am working entirely in C. Again, all this works just fine. The nearest object is selected correctly (I know this because I color the object red that is currently selected, using the `selected` variable, in my rendering function). But that's really not enough information, because just based on this the pointer at the center of the screen could be pointing to any one of that object's faces. I want to be able to select an individual face on the object, while also being able to identify that the object itself is selected. The two things I have tried so far are: 1) using `glPushName` and `glPopName` instead of `glLoadName` for drawing each object in the `pickObject` function, then having a `glPushName` and `glPopName` for each individual face int the `drawObject` function, but that has not yielded the results I would like, and 2) making a completely separate function called `pickFace` that I run right after the `pickObject` function. It does the same thing, but only renders the currently elected object and sets the variable `selectedFace` instead of `selected`. My guess is that this is the most inefficient way to achieve what I want, however, so although it works, I'd like to know if there's a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer to this actually makes me fee rather silly for posting it, because it was an easy fix that I somehow kept overlooking. Using `glPushName` and `glPopName` for each object as we as each face would have worked, if I had corrected the way I retrieved the ids from the select buffer afterwards. so the `drawObject` function turns into this:

```
void drawObject(int i)
{
    glPushName(0);
    renderFace0(i);
    glPopName();

    glPushName(1);
    renderFace1(i);
    glPopName();

    glPushName(2);
    renderFace2(i);
    glPopName();

    glPushName(3);
    renderFace3(i);
    glPopName();
}
```

And the corrections for 'pickObject' function are:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < NUM_OBJECTS; i ++)
{
    glPushName(i);
    drawObject(i);
    glPopName();
}

hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
if(hits > 0)
{
    int znear;
    znear = selectBuffer[2];
    selected = selectBuffer[3];
    selectedFace = selectBuffer[4];

    for(i = 1; i < hits; i ++)
    {
        if(selectBuffer[5 * i + 2] > znear)
        {
            znear = selectBuffer[5 * i + 2];
            selected = selectBuffer[5 * i + 3];
            selectedFace = selectBuffer[5 * i + 4];
        }
    }

} else selected = -1;
```

The big change I missed was changing `i * 4` in the indexing to `i * 5`, because since I'm looking for two names in each selection, the selection buffer would be layed out something like: `{number of names hit, far value, near value, first name, second name, ...}` and then that pattern repeats. So my step size had to change from 4 to 5, because with two names per hit there are now 5 data values in the select buffer per hit instead of 4.